# Ошибка ввода информации в базу данных

Tags: php, sql

При попытки ввнести информацию в базу данных, ввод не проходит. Выдает ошибку. Как можно исправить? Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код на форму:

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Actors</title>
    <link href="../public/stylesheets/films.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
        <form method="POST" action="add_actor.php" class="form">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Add Actors Form</legend>
            <div class="container">
              <label for='first_name'>First Name</label><br />
              <input type="name" placeholder="first_name" name="first_name" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><br />
              <input type="name" placeholder="last_name" name="last_name" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <label for="gender">Gender</label><br />
              <select name="gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
              </select><br />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <label for="birth_year">Year Born</label><br />
              <input type="name" placeholder="year" name="birth_year" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class='container'>
              <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

И вот код на обрабатывающий файл:

```html
<?php
  $servername = "localhost"; $username = "webuser"; $password = "secret1234";
  $dbname = "movies_db";

  // Check connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  else{
    echo "<h1>Connected successfully</h1>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'actors' ('actors_firstname', 'actors_lastname', 'actors_gender', 'actors_birthyear') VALUES
    ('".$_POST['first_name']."','".$_POST['last_name']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['birth_year']."')";

    $res2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($res2 === TRUE){
      echo "<h1>New record created successfully</h1>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<h1>Insert failed</h1>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте в код `var_dump(mysqli_error($conn))`, после  `echo "<h1>Insert failed</h1>"` и дополните свой вопрос тем, что выведет `var_dump`

Comment: 'actors' и далее - кавычки неправильные. Или вообще уберите, или ставьте косые.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, спасибо за подсказку!